# Haskell library to parse configuration from command-line or environment variables

Tags: haskell, environment-variables, flags

I'm fairly new to Haskell, so apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

I'm looking for a library that can parse command line flags, but in cases where the flags aren't provided on the command line, can also obtain values from environment variables. I've tried some Google and Hackage searches, but couldn't find anything like that. Does such a library exist, or is there some other best-practice for handling such things?

Comment: I guess if you remove the mention of "library" from the question, it may be a valid question. You could also provide more detailed description of the problem, e.g. How to obtain a value of the application parameter FOO that can come from either command-line or environment variable. You'd also better provide some attempt of yours to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`System.Environment`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/System-Environment.html) module in `Base` package. Specifically `getArgs` and `getEnv`.